# One of workers crashed. Cause: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

I just installed KCC so I can read manga to my Kindle paperwhite 5 however im having an issue where it says that one of the codes is in float cannot be interpreted as integer. I tried to traceback and modify the codes by adjusting the classes from float to int but it seems that im doing it wrong. It would be highly appreciated if you could assist me.

```
 Traceback:
  File "/home/jpvergara/kcc/kindlecomicconverter/comic2ebook.py", line 563, in imgFileProcessing
    img.autocontrastImage()
  File "/home/jpvergara/kcc/kindlecomicconverter/image.py", line 261, in autocontrastImage
    self.image = ImageOps.autocontrast(Image.eval(self.image, lambda a: 255 * (a / 255) ** gamma))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3100, in eval
    return image.point(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1676, in point
    return self._new(self.im.point(lut, mode))
```

Comment: Im actually using the version of KCC where Paperwhite 5 is supported and unfortunately itś the only way :(

Answer (score 0):

You're not converting anything to an integer. In this line:

```
self.image = ImageOps.autocontrast(Image.eval(self.image, lambda a: 255 * (a / 255) ** gamma))
```

`255 * (a / 255) ** gamma` will produce a float, because you're dividing `a` by 255. In order to convert to an integer wrap everything in `int()` like so:

```
self.image = ImageOps.autocontrast(Image.eval(self.image, lambda a: int(255 * (a / 255) ** gamma)))
```

Just as a note, `int()` will simply discard any decimal values, it's basically rounding down -> so e.g. `int(1.1)` and `int(1.9)` will both become 1. If you want 'standard' rounding (where the cut off is at 0.5), use for example `int(numpy.round(255 * (a / 255) ** gamma)))`. And to explicitly round up or down use `numpy.ceil()` or `numpy.floor()`, respectively.